# Sorting JSON array into multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have the following json array

```
{"label":[{"name":"Government Schools",
          "datapoints":[{"year":"2007-2008","total":"1300"},
                        {"year":"2008-2009","total":"1280"},
                        {"year":"2009-2010","total":"1100"},
                        {"year":"2010-2011","total":"1400"}]
         },
         {"name":"Total Schools",
          "datapoints":[{"year":"2007-2008","total":"900"},
                        {"year":"2008-2009","total":"1000"},
                        {"year":"2009-2010","total":"1300"},
                        {"year":"2010-2011","total":"999"}]
         }]
}
```

I am trying to sort the datapoints into an array with the following format

```
var linedataline = [{dataPoints : [{ x: 1,
                                        y: 1300,
                                        label: "2007-2008"
                                    }, {
                                        x: 2,
                                        y: 1280,
                                        label: "2008-2009"
                                    }, {
                                        x: 3,
                                        y: 1100,
                                        label: "2009-2010"
                                    }, {
                                        x: 4,
                                        y: 1400,
                                        label: "2010-2011"
                                    }]
                                },
                                {dataPoints : [{ x: 1,
                                        y: 900,
                                        label: "2007-2008"
                                    }, {
                                        x: 2,
                                        y: 1000,
                                        label: "2008-2009"
                                    }, {
                                        x: 3,
                                        y: 1300,
                                        label: "2009-2010"
                                    }, {
                                        x: 4,
                                        y: 999,
                                        label: "2010-2011"
                                    }]

                            }];
```

I have used the following javascript

```
for(var i=0; i<data.label.length;i++){
                datapoints.length = 0;
                for(var j=0;j<data.label[i].datapoints.length;j++){
                    datapoints.push({
                                x: j+1,
                                y: data.label[i].datapoints[j].total,
                                label: data.label[i].datapoints[j].year
                    })
                }
                linedataline.push({ 
                        dataPoints: datapoints 
                })     
            }
```

where "data" is the parsed JSON. The problem is that linedataline does contain two arrays as required, but both print the second JSON array and not the first one. If I do not empty the datapoints array, it returns both the arrays but linedataline has array length = 8 and it does not separate the two arrays. What is the problem here?

Comment: That doesn't really have anything to do with sorting or JSON. You seem to want to convert an array of objects into a different format/structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `datapoints.length = 0;` with `var datapoints = [];`

```
var data = {"label":[{"name":"Government Schools",
          "datapoints":[{"year":"2007-2008","total":"1300"},
                        {"year":"2008-2009","total":"1280"},
                        {"year":"2009-2010","total":"1100"},
                        {"year":"2010-2011","total":"1400"}]
         },
         {"name":"Total Schools",
          "datapoints":[{"year":"2007-2008","total":"900"},
                        {"year":"2008-2009","total":"1000"},
                        {"year":"2009-2010","total":"1300"},
                        {"year":"2010-2011","total":"999"}]
         }]
};
var linedataline = [];
for(var i=0; i<data.label.length;i++){
                var datapoints = [];
                for(var j=0;j<data.label[i].datapoints.length;j++){
                    datapoints.push({
                                x: j+1,
                                y: data.label[i].datapoints[j].total,
                                label: data.label[i].datapoints[j].year
                    });
                }
                linedataline.push({ 
                        dataPoints: datapoints 
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create new instance.

```
for(var i=0; i<data.label.length;i++){
  var datapoints = [];
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes I have it created. Havent mentioned it in the code here. I have created all the instances.

Comment: But you miss to create new instance for each datapoints in the loop.

Comment: Oh, I had all the arrays created outside the loops. I hadn't created an instance inside the loop. This seems to work. Thank you so much!